# libURL not working if using {symbol:'url(...)'} in highcharts exporting

Tags: highcharts

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
```

**without using the image button**

```
exporting : {  
  libURL:contextPathGlobal+'/scripts/lib/highcharts/',
  enabled: true,
  buttons: {customButton: {symbol: 'round'})
}
```

while downloading .pdf format using the above snipet  ,

*jspdf* and *svg2pdf* are fetch from defined path in libURL and .pdf format download  successfully in client side serverexport

**using the url in *buttons {customButton:{symbol:'url'}}***

```
exporting : {  
  libURL:contextPathGlobal+'/scripts/lib/highcharts/',
  enabled: true,
  buttons: {customButton: {symbol: 'url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inverticons-stroke-vol-3/32/share_export-16.png)})
}
```

but using the **url** in custom button it may leads to highcharts server for exporting pdf format

Want to export pdf format in client side exporting while using url in symbol

Comment: It seems that you have syntax error in your symbol param. 

Fixed: ```buttons: {
      customButton: {
        symbol: 'url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inverticons-stroke-vol-3/32/share_export-16.png)'
      },
    },```

Could you test it with the right value and let me know if problem still exists?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MuraliKaliappan/rs88kLw3/1/

Comment: When I click on your custom symbol, there is an error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined```  which seems to be different than you reported. Could you point me if demo is correct?

Comment: thats doesn't matter, need to know how to export pdf format  in client side with using of url in symbol property.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MuraliKaliappan/rs88kLw3/2/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is already reported to our developers here:

- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7774

Workaround

```
// Override to always force basic local export
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.exportChartLocal = function(exportingOptions, chartOptions) {
  var chart = this,
    options = Highcharts.merge(chart.options.exporting, exportingOptions);

  chart.getSVGForLocalExport(
    options,
    chartOptions,
    function() {
      console.error("Something went wrong");
    },
    function(svg) {
      Highcharts.downloadSVGLocal(
        svg,
        options,
        function() {
          console.error("Something went wrong");
        }
      );
    }
  );
};
```

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/2578sz52/